# jquery datepicker getdate return null

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

when I use `JQuery` `datapicker` `getDate`, it returns null.
I need two `datepickers`, the second one should be smaller than the first one.

the JS file is like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var today = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
    (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
    (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;

var startDate;
$( function() {
    $( "#start-date" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        inline: true,
        minDate:'2016-01-01',
        maxDate:today,
        });


    startDate =$( "#start-date" ).datepicker("getDate");
    if(startSDate==null){ 
    startSDate = '2016-01-01'
    }

    $( "#end-date" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    inline: true,
    minDate:startDate,
    maxDate:today,

        });
  } );
```

However, this does not work. Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wendysun0315/uqe1btdc/2/).

Comment: What exactly do you want..?? I mean on selection of the first calender date, second calender should automatically get the minimum date as the date selected in first calender.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following code.

```
    'use strict';
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var today = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
    (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
    (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;
var fullSDate;
$( function() {
    $( "#start-date" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        inline: true,
        minDate:'2016-05-12',
        maxDate:today,
        });

    $( "#end-date" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            inline: true,
            minDate:fullSDate,
            maxDate:today       
    });

    $("#end-date").focusin(function(){
        fullSDate =$( "#start-date" ).datepicker("getDate");
        if(fullSDate==null){ 
             fullSDate = '2016-01-01'
        }
        $( "#end-date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", fullSDate);

    });     
  } );
```

Refer this [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/uqe1btdc/5/)

Answer (score 1):

it is null because you are assigning startDate variable at very first time when your jquery file is loading and that time there is no date in $( "#start-date" ) control when you are trying to get date.

You should assign your startDate variable on $( "#start-date" ).datepicker onselect event like this

```
   var startDate;

   $("#start-date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    inline: true,
    minDate:'2016-01-01',
    maxDate:today,
    onSelect: function () {
        startDate =$("#start-date" ).datepicker("getDate");
    }
    });

  $("#end-date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    inline: true,
    minDate:startDate,
    maxDate:today
    });
```